# Regex - Matching a string within an email address

Tags: javascript, regex

So my problem is I am looking to match a certain combination of letters at the start of an email address followed by an @ and then a wildcard, for example:

admin@* OR noreply@* OR spam@* OR subscribe@

Can this be done?

Comment: Try and look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ read up and practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^(?:admin|noreply|spam|subscribe)@\S*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ve7m)

You need an anchor at the start to avoid matching address with other characters before. If the string contains only the email address use `^` at the beginning, this matches the start of the string. If the email address is surrounded by other text, the use `\b` this is a word boundary.

`(?:admin|noreply|spam|subscribe)` is a non capturing group, becuase of the `?:` at the start, then there is a list of alternatives, divided by the `|` character.

`\S*` is any amount of non white characters, this will match addresses that are not valid, but should not hurt too much.

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for grouping with the | operator. The following will do what you want.

edit: Since your using this for an email server rules you won't need to match the entire string, only part of it. In that case you will need to use ^ to specify the start of the string and then drop the domain portion since we don't care about what it is.

```
^(admin|noreply|spam|subscribe)@
```

Comment: I think your `[\w.]` is too restrictive, something like `\S` (a non whitespace character) would be probably better.

Comment: Will this guarantee they will be at the start of the emails address? For instance 'dadmin' or 'emspam' would not be matched? Thanks for your help folks! I'm a bit new to this.

Answer (score 0):

sure thing!

```
[A-Za-z]+@.+
```

says any letters at least once but any number of times, then an at sign, then anything (other than newline) for your specific examples use

```
(admin|noreply|spam|subscribe)@.+
```

Comment: Will this guarantee they will be at the start of the emails address? For instance 'dadmin' or 'emspam' would not be matched? Thanks for your help folks! I'm a bit new to this

Comment: to make sure they are at the start of the email you could use the ^ character at the start if you are just trying to match emails.  However if you are trying to search for emails in a long string of text then use \s instead right before. ^ says this has to be the start of the string but \s says this has to be whitespace before the email starts.  you can check it out [here.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)